# Deployed Amazon SES .Net Core on Windows Server fails sending emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-ses

I have a .Net Core web application hosted on a windows VPS (Not on AWS). When I test sending the email on windows locally on my dev machine, everything works fine and emails are sent successfully.

Now having deployed the same application into production on the Windows VPS. Sending the email fails with the following error message:

> One or more errors occurred. (Unable to get IAM security credentials
> from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.)

I am currently using the following dependencies for AWS SES.

```
using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;
```

I configured aws locally, set up the profile and credentials. When I encountered this error in production for the first time, I thought may be I need to also configure the profile on the server. So I did the same on the VPS but still when the form is submitted in order to send the email. It still fails with the same error.

What do I need to do in order to fix this issue?

Comment: How did you set up the profile and credentials? What is inside `%UserProfile%/.aws/`? Yes, you will need to provide the VPS with AWS credentials to be able to call SES.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I used aws configure on the server to provide both access key id and the secret access key but still it doesn't work.